# Cannot Retrieve Everything out of a Stack

Tags: c++, stack

I'm having a little trouble understanding why this code does not output as I expected? Any ideas?

Output: ? you are

Expected: ? you are how Hello,

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <stack> 
#include <string> 
using namespace std; 

 int main() 
 { 
     stack<string> sentence; 

     sentence.push("Hello,"); 
     sentence.push("how"); 
     sentence.push("are"); 
     sentence.push("you"); 
     sentence.push("?"); 

     for (int i=0; i<sentence.size(); ++i) { 
         cout << sentence.top() << " "; 
         sentence.pop(); 
     } 
     cout << endl; 

     return 0; 
 }
```

Comment: Think about what the size of the stack is when you pop an item from it.  Try `while(!sentence.empty())` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because calling sentence.pop() decreases stack size by 1 AND you're increasing i at the same time. You'll only get half of the values this way.

Do this instead:

```
 while (!sentence.empty()){ 
     cout << sentence.top() << " "; 
     sentence.pop(); 
 }
```

Comment: Change 'sentece.size() > 0' to 'sentence.size() > 0'. Or better yet, '!sentence.empty()'.

Comment: @traal: you can write your own answers, you know that?

Comment: @traal: Your first suggestion is a tautology, and your second is useless.

Answer (score 2):

When you issue pop() the size of the stack is decremented while variable i is increased independently of the size of the stack. I advice to substitute your loop for the following one

```
 while  ( !sentence.empty() ) { 
     cout << sentence.top() << " "; 
     sentence.pop(); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're popping the stack inside the loop,  you're changing it's size,  affecting how many times the loop executes.

I would instead do:

```
while (!sentence.empty())
{
    cout << sentence.top() << " ";
    sentence.pop();
}
```